# Prevent logger from printing any stack trace

Tags: java, exception, logging, log4j

I have found many posts about "how to make log4j printing stack trace of exception", but I haven't found any solution to prevent it from any printing stack trace.
The result I want to see on exception is:

```
File was already edited
Operation finished with exception
```

But the thing I get is all the time:
`24 [main] FATAL com.me.abc - File was already edited`

Answer (score 0):

I guess one way could be: You can have your own logger by inheriting the existing logger. In this logger you can decide your own behavior. Along with this have your own class loader and load this new logger class instead of the  existing one.